# Getting accurate Mouse Coordinates on a Video Element

Tags: javascript, html, video, coordinates

I am having some problems involving full screening in video elements:

I have a code which tracks X and Y cords as mouse moves over video elem:

```
<video id="video" preload=auto autoplay controls>
<source src = "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/79/Big_Buck_Bunny_small.ogv">
</video>

function getElementCSSSize(el) {
    var cs = getComputedStyle(el);
    var w = parseInt(cs.getPropertyValue("width"), 10);
    var h = parseInt(cs.getPropertyValue("height"), 10);
    return {width: w, height: h}
}

function mouseHandler(event) {
    var size = getElementCSSSize(this);
    var scaleX = this.videoWidth / size.width;
    var scaleY = this.videoHeight / size.height;

    var rect = this.getBoundingClientRect();  // absolute position of element
    var x = ((event.clientX - rect.left) * scaleX + 0.5)|0; // round to integer
    var y = ((event.clientY - rect.top ) * scaleY + 0.5)|0;
    console.log("x " + x);
    console.log("y " + y);


}

video.addEventListener("mousemove", mouseHandler);
```

Now, it works perfectly well when the video is viewed on normal mode;
if for example the video is 237x132, 
then max left is 0x, and max top is 0y.

The problem occurs in full mode; 
there are black borders on top and bottom as you can see:
https://i.imgsafe.org/452a426.jpg

now, this is true to every video I checked.
 So in my script above, for some reason it counts the
 black borders as part of the video; the x is ok, but
the y is not; the y starts at the top corner of
 the video, upon the black border.

I need to be very precice here, and to completely ignore somehow the black borders - the y should start at the real pixel and end at the real pixel.
So, every type of movie that is played in full mode should is supposed to ignore the black borders.

Thank you so much for your time.

Answer (score 0):

```
function mouseHandler(event) {
    var rect = this.getBoundingClientRect();
    if (!('height' in rect)) {//for IE8
        rect.height = rect.bottom - rect.top;
        rect.width = rect.right - rect.left;
    }
    var actualVideoHeight = rect.height;
    var actualVideoWidth = rect.width;
    var borderTop = 0;
    var borderLeft = 0;
    var onBottomBorder = false;
    var onRightBorder = false;
    var videoRatio = this.videoWidth / this.videoHeight;
    var elementRatio = rect.width / rect.height;
    if (videoRatio > elementRatio) {//video is wider than element
        actualVideoHeight = this.videoHeight * rect.width / this.videoWidth;//actual height of video without borders
        borderTop = (rect.height - actualVideoHeight) / 2;//calculate size of top border
        if (event.clientY > actualVideoHeight + borderTop) {//check if mouse in on bottom border
            onBottomBorder = true;
        }
    } else if (videoRatio < elementRatio) {//element is wider than video
        actualVideoWidth = this.videoWidth * rect.height / this.videoHeight;//actual width of video without borders
        borderLeft = (rect.width - actualVideoWidth) / 2;//calculate size of left border
        if (event.clientX > Math.round(actualVideoWidth + borderLeft)) {//check if mouse in on right border
            //onRightBorder = true;
        }
    }
    var x = Math.round((event.clientX - rect.left - borderLeft) * (this.videoWidth / actualVideoWidth)); //scale and round to integer
    var y = Math.round((event.clientY - rect.top - borderTop) * this.videoHeight / actualVideoHeight);
    /*
    x will be negative if mouse is on left border
    y will be negative if mouse is on top border
    onRightBorder will be true if mouse is on right border
    onBottomBorder will be true if mouse is on bottom border
    */
    if (y > 0 && x > 0 && !onRightBorder && !onBottomBorder) {
        console.log('x ' + x);
        console.log('y ' + y);
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, it doesn't work. I tried using full screen, and it says that y = 0 kinda in the middle of the video.

Comment: I have fixed it and edit the answer. There was a small typing error. I have tested it and it works now.

Comment: This is almost perfect. problem is, on full screen, when you go to the bottom pixel, you can clearly see that it's not entirely accurate - the Y number is a little less than it should be. For example, if the height of the video is supposed to be 176, then on full screen, you will see 156 on the bottom corner. I've checked a number of videos, and the bottom corner is almost accurate, but not exactly. Nevertheless, THANK YOU so much for your effort man. I really appreciate it, just what should I do with that small inaccuracy?

Comment: The scaling was done with element's size and not the video's actual size. I have fixed that. Also the function getElementCSSSize should not be required as getBoundingClientRect gets the height and width.

Comment: Thank you, just one thing; on full screen, the bottom Y is 1 more than it should be. for example: Height of video is 480, bottom Y height is 481. and on normal mode it's contrary: it's one less than it should be; for  example: Height of video is 480, bottom height Y in normal mode 479. Nevertheless thank you, I think I can just do manually -1 to everything. Or is there other way around this? anyways THANK YOU.

Comment: I am not sure about what's causing this problem. Were you able to get the coordinates of the last pixel with the original function that you posted?

Comment: I am getting one pixel less in both normal and fullscreen mode

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106221/discussion-between-naman-nehra-and-runningfromshia).